# eclipse CDT shows Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: ... ' for lambda expressions

Tags: c++, lambda, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)
Build id: 20200615-1200

C/C++ Development Tools
Version: 9.11.1.202006011430
Build id: 20200601-1605

Arch Linux with gcc 10.2.0

Given the following minimal example

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>

struct LinkedElement {
    uint8_t index = 0;
    LinkedElement* next = nullptr;
};

static LinkedElement* linkedList;

LinkedElement* FindLinkedElement(std::function<bool(LinkedElement*)> filter)
{
    for (auto elem = linkedList; elem != nullptr; elem = elem->next)
    {
        if (filter(elem))
        {
            return elem;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto broken = FindLinkedElement([](LinkedElement* le){ return le->index > 0; });
    auto works = FindLinkedElement(nullptr);
}
```

eclipse will underline the first `FindLinkedElement` in `main()` as a "Semantic Error" (as determined by the Problems view) with the following error message

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
LinkedElement * FindLinkedElement(std::function<bool (LinkedElement *)>)
'
```

The second line is not marked as an error. The compiler is totally fine with all of this code. How can I get eclipse to not treat this as an error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` 10.2.0. Now running `9_2020_q2_update` I see no more errors in eclipse.